# PHP use "use" of the interface over concrete classes

Tags: php, oop

Have encountered an issue I can't seem to figure out now by myself.

Using Symfony autoload module.

Here's my factory:

```
namespace Core\Factories;

use \Core\Gateway;

class DatabaseAccessFactory {
    // Define client type
    const DEF = 'mongo';

    public function createObject($type) {
        switch($type) {
            case self::DEF:
                return new MongoClientGateway();
                break;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Example of /Core/Gateway/MongoClientGateway.php

```
<? namespace Core\Gateway;

class MongoClientGateway implements MongoDbGateway {
    public function setUp(){

    }

    public function query(){

    }

    public function save(){

    }
}
```

So, basically I'm using "use" keyword to load gateway namespace into my current one, and then I try to instantiate a class that is under \Core\Gateway namespace, but it says class is not found. Am I missing something?

Comment: I would recommend throwing an exception from `DatabaseAccessFactory::createObject()` if `$type` is not supported, i.e. `throw new InvalidArgumentException($type);` instead of `return false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specifcy the class as well

```
use Core\Gateway\MongoClientGateway
```

or access the class with the namespace you used

```
new Gateway\MongoClientGateway
```

Btw, there's no need for the first "\" in use \Core\Gateway

Comment: There's no way to avoid using concrete class names in import?

Comment: use Core\Gateway\MongoClientGateway as MongoGateway; should do the trick, or what do you mean exactly by concrete class names?

Comment: Well, that should be enough, I understand the problem now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. It's `use Foo\Bar`, without leading backslash.
2. `use Foo\Bar` does not mean that every `Class` implicitly resolves to `Foo\Bar\Class` now. `use Foo\Bar` is shorthand for `use Foo\Bar as Bar`, so you can reference the namespace `Foo\Bar` using merely `Bar`. `use` is not *"importing a namespace"*, it's *aliasing* a namespace to a shorter name.
3. Therefore you need to write `Gateway\MongoClientGateway`, or `use Core\Gateway\MongoClientGateway` explicitly if you want to be able to write just `MongoClientGateway`.

Answer (score 0):

you used "use" wrong.
waht "use" does, is to tell your code where class comes from.

sample code:

```
use \my\namespace\className

new ClassName();
```

this will make the className accassible without a namespace.